# Issue with Opentok and CallKit

Tags: ios, swift, opentok, callkit

I am trying to use `Opentok` and `CallKit` for audio and video calling purpose, I have followed this demo provided by OpenTok https://github.com/opentok/CallKit/tree/master/CallKitDemo

The issue I am facing is when I am doing audio call to another person it starts speaker instead of Built-in-Receiver. I tried their demo and it also has the same issue.

Then I tried https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017290 which is provided by Apple, but after implementing the `AudioController`, the new call starts with Built-in-Speaker and it automatically switched to Speaker and there is no way to make output change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to implement a custom audio driver with setting up the `AVAudioSession`

```
         var audioOptions: UInt {
            if isSpeaker {
                return AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker.rawValue |
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers.rawValue |
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue |
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowAirPlay.rawValue

            } else {
                return AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers.rawValue |
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue |
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowAirPlay.rawValue |
                    AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.duckOthers.rawValue
            }
        }
        if isSpeaker {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat, options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: audioOptions))
        } else {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat, options: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: audioOptions))
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you publishing your stream?

```
 let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
 settings.name = "\(userID)"
 guard let publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings) 
  else {
        return
    }
    yourStream = publisher
    yourStream?.publishAudio = false
    yourStream?.publishVideo = true
    var error: OTError?
    session?.publish(publisher, error: &error)
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }

    guard let publisherView = publisher.view else {
        return
    }
   participantVideoView.addSubview(publisherView)
```

Comment: Yes, I did the same thing.